# Invalid RSS Feed. Undefined item element: content

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, rss, feed

When I run http://www.virtualfestivals.com/syndication/rss/news.rss.xml through http://validator.w3.org/feed/ I get the error message

```
Undefined item element: content (20 occurrences)
<content><![CDATA[<p>While their virtuoso musici...
```

However, as per http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/howto/declare_namespaces.html, I am declaring the namespace `xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"` at the start

Has anyone got any pointers? I'm baffled!

**[UPDATE]**

When I try and use the `encoded` bit as suggested, an error happens when I create the RSS.

I am using XSL and ColdFusion. Nothing drastic, it just breaks when I add the `encoded` part.

WORKS: `<content><xsl:value-of select="maintext" /></content>`

DOESN'T WORK: `<content:encoded><xsl:value-of select="maintext" /></content:encoded>`

Comment: Have you declared the `content` namespace prefix in the stylesheet?

Comment: Arghhhhhh - I did add it but for whatever reason, it wasn't at the top when I went to edit!!! Sorted!!!

Answer (score -1):

You declare it, but you never use it. And the proper tag name is `encoded`.

```
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>The band...
```

Comment: I do use it don't I? Nevermind! 

When I try and use the encoded bit, an error happens when I create the RSS.

I am using XSL and ColdFusion. Nothing drastic, it just breaks when I add the encoded part

Comment: Kind of what? ColdFusion just says "Failed to compile stylesheet"

Comment: So then put the stylesheet through a tool that gives more information, such as `xsltproc`.